# How the drag the sortable list with in sortable container in react-sortable-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I am using react-sortable-dnd to sort list , i want to sort list with in a x-axis of a div container, but the sort item is draggable to entire x-axis, i have given following configuration

```
<SortableList items={items} onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd} lockAxis="y"  lockToContainerEdges={true} />
```

Comment: Can you add some code or some fiddle to show us what exact issue  you have :)

Comment: @AkhilAravind here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-star-u7zhr   , i issue is the sort item card should not be draggable outside of the container

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lockToContainerEdges` prop for the `sortableContainer` itself. In your case it will work.

```
<SortableList
    lockToContainerEdges={true}
    items={this.state.items}
    onSortEnd={this.onSortEnd}
    lockAxis="y"
  />
```

I've checked it on your provided example and it works. Also noticed that in code example here you show this prop but in codesandbox didn't use

For reference you could visit https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc for more info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33548105)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense obviously. I updated my comment with useful info